# Creating new keystore in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

One of my friends helped me make an android app and he used his keystore on the app now the app is in market. I can not add new version now without that keystore and his password. Is it possible for him to make a new keystore (so that he can give me his old keystore file and password)? Is it easy or is it even possible? Can someone please guide me how to do this if that is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye its possible for your friend to help you out.The packages u upload to market must be signed by account-owners public key.Follow [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) link

Comment: It does not talk about creating a new Keystore anywhere in that link? Can he create a new keystore some how and give me the old keystore and password?

Comment: if you look properly,the page gives you commands that you need to create a keystore and how to export an apk file using that keystore...
eg  
    $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Comment: or you can do it in eclispe as
file->export->Android->Export Android Application->
then choose a project after that you will have option  to create new keystore